# OpenLdap - error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A

Tags: apache, ssl, openldap, apacheds

I need to connect ApacheDS database using startTLS with OpenLDAP client.
My ldaprc file contains:

```
URI ldap://127.0.0.1:7323 ldaps://127.0.0.1:7423
SSL start_tls
SASL_MECH plain
TLSCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:+TLSv1:!SSLv2:+SSLv3
TLS_REQCERT allow
```

Command that I've used is:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://localhost:7323 -D "uid=admin,ou=system" -w secret -Z -d1
```

I've checked, my server is listening on these ports, I'm able to connect with other clients (e.g. ldapbrowser, jxplorer), but tests with OpenLdap fails:

...

> ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 127.0.0.1:7323
>  ldap_pvt_connect:
>   fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0
>  ldap_open_defconn: successful
>   ldap_send_server_request
>  ber_scanf fmt ({it) ber:
>   ber_scanf fmt ({) ber:
>  ber_flush2: 31 bytes to sd 3
>   ldap_result ld 0x7f81d95282a0 msgid 1
>  wait4msg ld 0x7f81d95282a0
>   msgid 1 (infinite timeout)
>  wait4msg continue ld 0x7f81d95282a0
>   msgid 1 all 1
>   ** ld 0x7f81d95282a0 Connections:
>   * host: 127.0.0.1  port: 7323  (default)
>    refcnt: 2  status: Connected
>    last used: Tue Dec  8 09:51:45 2015
>
> ** ld 0x7f81d95282a0 Outstanding Requests:
>   * msgid 1,  origid 1, status InProgress
>     outstanding referrals 0, parent count
>   0
>    ld 0x7f81d95282a0 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
>   ** ld 0x7f81d95282a0 Response Queue:
>     Empty
>    ld 0x7f81d95282a0 response count 0
>  ldap_chkResponseList ld
>   0x7f81d95282a0 msgid 1 all 1
>  ldap_chkResponseList returns ld
>   0x7f81d95282a0 NULL
>  ldap_int_select
>  read1msg: ld
>   0x7f81d95282a0 msgid 1 all 1
>  ber_get_next
>  ber_get_next:
>   tag 0x30 len 38 contents:
>  read1msg: ld 0x7f81d95282a0 msgid 1
>   message type extended-result
>  ber_scanf fmt ({eAA) ber:
>   read1msg: ld 0x7f81d95282a0 0 new referrals
>  read1msg:  mark
>   request completed, ld 0x7f81d95282a0 msgid 1
>  request done: ld
>   0x7f81d95282a0 msgid 1
>  res_errno: 0, res_error: <>, res_matched:
>   <>
>  ldap_free_request (origid 1, msgid 1)
>   ldap_parse_extended_result
>  ber_scanf fmt ({eAA) ber:
>   ber_scanf fmt (a) ber:
>  ber_scanf fmt (O) ber:
>   ldap_parse_result
>  ber_scanf fmt ({iAA) ber:
>  ber_scanf fmt
>   (x) ber:
>  ber_scanf fmt (x) ber:
>  ber_scanf fmt (}) ber: ldap_msgfree
>  TLS trace: SSL_connect:before/connect
>   initialization
>  TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client
>   hello A
>  TLS trace: SSL3 alert read:fatal:unexpected_message TLS trace: SSL_connect:error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
>   TLS: can't connect: error:140773F2:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert unexpected message.
>   ldap_err2string
>  ldap_start_tls: Connect error (-11)
>           additional info: error:140773F2:SSLroutines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert
>   unexpected message

Any idea what am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: It looks like the server didn't understand STARTTLS, but why that followed the request is a mystery.

Comment: try to take a tcpdump network capture. You'll see things more clearly with it !